# How are websites permitted to make other companies' fonts available?

Tags: font-licensing

If I want to use - say - ITC Benguiat, I can purchase a licence for it at https://www.myfonts.com/collections/benguiat-font-itc.

It'll cost me £450.99 for an annual webfont licence, that allows me to use it in my websites. Fair enough.

But I can also go to literally dozens of sites such as https://www.free-fonts.com, which all make ITC Benguiat available, and tell me that I can use free "for personal use". Some of them even provide URLs that will allow me to load it directly from their servers into my website.

On what basis do these websites get to offer me someone else's typeface? There's no indication that Monotype - the publisher of ITC Benguiat - has made it available under such licensing conditions.

Are these sites not in violation of the owner's copyright? Would I, using the font, not be in violation of the owner's copyright?

Comment: This is a *legal* question, not a design question.

Comment: And be aware *most* of these free sites are **not** making "ITC Benguiat" (or similar) available. They are making *similarly named knock offs* available, not the International Type Corporation (ITC) version. So you may find "Benguiat" at the free sites, but not "ITC Benguiat". I may sell chicken and call it "Kentucky Deep Fried Chicken" - can't copyright chicken.... but that doesn't mean my chicken is the same as KFC chicken.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal question.

Comment: You are making the assumption that they are "allowed".  There are plenty font sites with dubious, possibly even illegal fonts for download.  It's up to you to check the licences. A judge won't care if you thought a font was free but actually isn't. You could still be sued for using it.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are computer software. The copyright owner may let his font to be freely downloadable, usable and even redistributable. There are many sites which distribute such fonts.

Then the copyright owner may allow private use, but tells that any paid usage nor installing it to be a part of a website or other software are not allowed, all such applications need a purchased license. For ex. dafont.com keeps available both fully free and free for private use fonts. Every font there has a license which tells what is allowed for free.

Finally there's numerous sites which simply keep available well crafted commercial fonts for free or for some low price. I mean fonts of Adobe, Linotype, Monotype, etc.., not coarse replicas made by hobbyists which may use nearly the same font name or even exactly the same name, if the name was established say 400 years ago. This is pure theft at least here in far west. Surely there are countries where nobody cares, because theft and pirating are there a long time tradition and also a respectable profession at least as long as the stolen property belongs to some foreigner. Some of these sites can be even in USA, but the pirated stuff is distributed to elsewhere, so they do not keep in their computers any stolen property. They may also have a warning: All fonts and other downloadables belong to their copyright owners. Do not use it without having a proper license from the copyright owners. Or they have inserted their own "license", for ex. Free to download and use in private applications.

If you use copyrighted stuff without paying the price the copyright owner wants or otherwise violate the limitations stated by him, you violate the copyright. Excuse "I downloaded it from a site which said it's free" doesn't change it. If that excuse neutralized a crime it would be used widely and it would make the whole copyright meaningless.

Why in the hell someone would set pirated stuff available for free? He may be an idealist who simply likes to cause harm. Or he can distribute specially treated versions which create a backdoor to your computer. By persuading people to download that specially treated stuff (not only fonts, anything which is attractive goes) they can collect a free army of machines which can be used for ex. to make denial of service attacks or to break codes or to distribute more malware.